# How does a service administrator get enough permission to create azure custom roles

Tags: azure, azure-resource-manager

I'm trying to create a [Custom Role](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/enterprisemobility/2015/12/10/custom-roles-in-azure-rbac-is-now-ga/) in azure (RBAC). But when I execute the powershell command `New-AzureRmRoleDefinition` here is the message I get saying that I'm not authorized to create it.

```
> New-AzureRmRoleDefinition .\developer_access_rbac.json


New-AzureRmRoleDefinition : AuthorizationFailed: The client 'admin@company.com' with object id
'{guid}' does not have authorization to perform action
'Microsoft.Authorization/roleDefinitions/write' over scope
'/providers/Microsoft.Authorization/roleDefinitions/{guid}'.
At line:1 char:1
+ New-AzureRmRoleDefinition .\developer_access_rbac.json
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : CloseError: (:) [New-AzureRmRoleDefinition], CloudException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.Azure.Commands.Resources.NewAzureRoleDefinitionCommand
```

I asked from one of our administrators in our organization and he says the account `admin@company.com` is already a Global Administrator. And in the active directory `admin@company.com` is displayed as a Service Administrator.

I'm a little confused by these permission levels in azure. Can anyone explain to me how to acquire the needed permission to the account `admin@company.com` for solving the issue.

Comment: Azure AD role != Azure subscription / resource group / resource role. You need a proper role on the Azure subscription.

Comment: Did you change assignable scopes? $role.AssignableScopes.Clear() $role.AssignableScopes.Add("/subscriptions/{subscriptionId}")

Comment: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/role-based-access-control-manage-access-powershell/. Scroll to "Create a custom role"

Comment: I encountered the same kind of issue. The problem was with the AssignableScopes section in the json file. Just needed to add: /subscriptions/<subscription id>

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Taken from https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/role-based-access-control-custom-roles/#custom-roles-access-control:

Who can create a custom role? Owners (and User Access Administrators) of subscriptions, resource groups, and resources can create custom roles for use in those scopes. The user creating the role needs to be able to perform Microsoft.Authorization/roleDefinition/write operation on all the AssignableScopes of the role.

Who can modify a custom role? Owners (and User Access Administrators) of subscriptions, resource groups, and resources can modify custom roles in those scopes. Users need to be able to perform the Microsoft.Authorization/roleDefinition/write operation on all the AssignableScopes of a custom role.

Who can view custom roles? All built-in roles in Azure RBAC allow viewing of roles that are available for assignment. Users who can perform the Microsoft.Authorization/roleDefinition/read operation at a scope can view the RBAC roles that are available for assignment at that scope.

Answer (score 2):

I actually came across this same issue and found the error to be misleading.

I had to clear the assignable scopes and then add one back.

```
$role.AssignableScopes.Clear()
$role.AssignableScopes.Add("/subscriptions/12345678912345789123456789")
```

Answer (score 2):

I encountered the same kind of issue. The problem was with the AssignableScopes section in the json file. Just needed to add: /subscriptions/